# how to test with custom dom event in angularjs

Tags: unit-testing, events, angularjs, karma-runner

I have written custom events for mobile devices in jasmine,
and I am trying to fire the events.

so instead of

```
angular.element()[0].click()
```

how may I trigger custom events and other events to trigger functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
angular.element().triggerHandler('my-custom-event-name');
```

If you want to attach additional data to your event:

```
angular.element().triggerHandler('my-custom-event-name', {'foo': 'bar'});
```

Comment: Will the additional data really work? And will it be attached to the event object that the handler is receiving? It doesn't seem that my handler is receiving any extra data. And according to jQuery docs triggerHandler takes an Array not an Object. (http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/)

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above post, you can pass a custom event (with extra data) by doing this:

```
angular.element().triggerHandler({
 'type': 'my-custom-event-name',
 'foo':  'bar' 
});
```